# JavaScript split function - use of escape characters?

Tags: javascript

The following two examples do the same thing.

I was wondering why Option 1 is given in a code example I found and not Option 2?

What is the significance of the forward/backward slashes in '/\&/'

Option 1.

```
    var pairs = qString.split(/\&/);
```

Option 2.

```
    var pairs = qString.split('&');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example splits on a [regular expression](http://www.evolt.org/node/36435) (constructed using the leaning-toothpick (`/.../`) syntax), while the second splits on a plain string.

Regular expressions are a powerful sub-language that allow complex string matching; in this case, the overhead of using one to split on a literal character (while probably negligible) is a little silly. It's like hiring a top-notch architect to build a wooden cube.

In the first example, the `&` character is mistakenly escaped (with the `\`), since it is not special in regular expressions. The regular expression engine gracefully handles that, however, and still treats it as a literal `&`.

Answer (score 3):

`split()` is a function that can take a regex as well as a string parameter, the forward slash usage is something called a regex literal and it is not really passing a string but a regex object.

The following statements in javascript are the same.

```
var regex = /\&/; // Literal
var regex = new RegExp("\\&"); // Explicit
```

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 uses a RegEx constant which is declared with surrounding forward slashed (`/`).

Option 2 uses a string.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions